# HIghcharts Legend Symbol Getting out of graph Canvas

Tags: jquery, angularjs, highcharts

I am using highcharts scatter chart and i want to display one specific data point legend more wider than other data points which i have implmented but the problem is when that point comes on x-axis or y-axis line it gets out of the graph canvas .

**Things I have tried**

offset
marginLeft

Screenshot

[image]

But i could not fix this issue.

Is there any alternate solution for this.

Comment: I am not sure what is your current issue, but maybe you can use renderer for making this dot? http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/Renderer

Answer (score 1):

If you want all of the points land within the plot border, and as long as you know your likely minimal data values, you could set a min on the xAxis and/or yAxis. See example, http://jsfiddle.net/7wd8vwxh/

```
xAxis: {
  title: {
    enabled: true,
    text: 'x axis title'
  },
  min: 150 // equal to a value lower than the lowest x value
},
yAxis: {
  title: {
    text: 'y axis title'
  },
  min: 0 // equal to a value lower than the lowest y value
},
```